# Call cdef function in cython cell magic

Tags: python, ipython, cython

I have a cython module saved as `foo.pyx` as follows:

```
cdef double sum(double[:] memview):
    cdef total = 0
    for i in range(len(memview):
        total += memview[i]
    return total
```

which I then compile with `!cython -a foo.pyx`.

I want to test this function in a `cython` cell magic as follows:

```
  In [1]: %%cython
     ...: import foo
     ...: cimport numpy as np
     ...: import numpy as np
     ...: def get_sum():
     ...:     cdef double[:] to_sum = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
     ...:     cdef double sum = foo.sum(to_sum)
     ...:     return sum
```

But when I try `get_sum()` I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, you need to cimport the cython module.
That will require a corresponding pxd that contains the function signature you wish to export from your module.
See the relevant part of the [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-c-functions) for a full working example.

This assumes that your files are all in the same working directory.
Otherwise, you will need to include the relevant folders containing the relevant folders containing the pyx and pxd files in the `include_dirs` argument passed to the `Extension` class constructor in your setup.py files for the different modules.

Comment: Perfect. Just was I was missing. Is there any smart way to create these `pxd` files or is it a manual job?

Comment: @LondonRob I'm not aware of any automated way to do it. All that is really necessary is copying the function signatures that you want to export. If the pyx file isn't too crazy, you could probably write a simple script to do it for you though.